Netbeans 21 can find Jruby plugin
Trying to install jruby on netbeans 21.  All info I can find appears outdated.  The Marven Repository appears to have what I am after but when attempt to install from it get 403 error.
Can anyone at least point me to the correct repository (or documentation) so I can make a start or
Easy install of jrbuy plugin all info outdated

NetBeans 21 does not support Ruby or Ruby on Rails, and old plugins won't work.
See the open and unresolved NetBeans bug report NETBEANS-6104 Add support for Ruby and Ruby on Rails programming languages which requests Ruby support as a feature addition. That was back in 2021.
Ruby is certainly still alive and kicking, but its popularity is declining. I suspect that Ruby support is unlikely to ever to be reimplemented unless someone decides to go ahead a write a new plugin that works.

Latest release of "JRuby 9.4.6.0 Released Tuesday, February 20 2024" so this must mean that Netbeans is no longer being used for an IDE by anyone is this correct?.  Can someone recommend a free or low-cost debugging  IDE. and compiling environment for JRuby.   I program strictly for personal use will go back to ruby and vs code if nothing available.

@user3285799 NetBeans hasn't formally supported Ruby since NetBeans 8.x, several years ago. Your best bet for JRuby may be to try Intellij IDEA with the Ruby plugin. Unfortunately you would need to pay for the "Ultimate Edition" to use that Ruby plugin. However, there is very recent documentation on how to Set up a Ruby development environment on Intellij IDEA, and their Ruby plugin was updated just yesterday!

Have given up on ruby will go back to Ruby on VSCode.
Thaks for the help
